# Is Geotoolkit up to date?

Tags: maven

I'm trying to change from Geotools to Geotoolkit but even the last code change is from [Jan 7, 2019](https://github.com/Geomatys/geotoolkit) its last release is from [Oct 27, 2017](https://github.com/Geomatys/geotoolkit/releases).

The maven repositories are even older.

How can I use an up to date Geotoolkit version from maven?